# How Create Sidenav from bottom to top

Tags: html, css

Is there anyone who can help me? How to open sidenav from bottom to top. This is the code from left to right. I want to make the code below open sidenav from bottom to top. This code now opens sidenav from left to right.

This is my CSS code:

```
.sidenav {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #111;
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
padding-top: 60px;
text-align:center;
}
```

And this is javascript code:

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

Can somebody help me correct the code, I am new.

Comment: awesome my friend... very verry thank... thank you so much....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this :

```js
function openNav() {
    document.querySelector(".sidenav").style.height = "100vh";
    document.querySelector(".sidenav").style.paddingTop = "60px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.querySelector(".sidenav").style.height = "0";
    document.querySelector(".sidenav").style.paddingTop = "0";
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
height: 0;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #111;
overflow-x: hidden;
transition:height 0.5s;
padding-top:0;
text-align:center;
}

button {
position:relative;
z-index:9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav"></div>
<!-- the button used for test -->
<button onClick='openNav()'>Open</button>
<button onClick='closeNav()'>Close</button>
```

Comment: thank you so much, code that you provide, work from top to bottom. How to open from the bottom to top brother?

Comment: @Abdullah i updated my answer to make ti work from bottom to top

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, you need to set `bottom: 0`

```
.sidenav {
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.height = "0";
}
```